# Invested 600 , now cot is required to release payments

Tags: trading, financial-literacy, scams, fraud, cryptocurrency

I invested 300 with this company Called CRYPTOPAIDOPTIONS and Option Flix. My concern is they are asking for cot to be sent to them before sending my payout . While another company name Alis Capital sends me my profits and just deducted everything off it . My questions is : is the cot real and should I send it ?

Comment: You didn't invest. You got scammed, and now they're trying to scam you more.

Comment: What does "cot" mean? Do you mean a certificate of title?

Answer (score 5):

Seems scam and there are similar complaints on trustpilot. Best is stay away from such sites

Answer (score 0):

This is the recent on-going scam. Do not send any more money to them. Before you invest with any company, make sure you check with others on forums, my bet is that you will meet someone that has used the site before. Stop rushing to make money quickly online. There is no quick money online aside gambling.